# MSQL-Cómo puedo hacer una actualización a una tabla en donde si el producto ya existe aumentar la cantidad pero si no existe ese producto insertarlo

Tags: mysql

Este es el código que tengo, pero no me funciona debido a que Productos_id y Usuarios_id no son llaves primarias, sino foráneas

```
INSERT INTO detalles_carrito (cantidad, precio, Productos_id, Usuario_id)
VALUES (1, 900.00, 13, 3) AS valores
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cantidad = detalles_carrito.cantidad + valores.cantidad;
```

Comment: Yo lo haría en código, algo así: `IF` el ID del producto en cuestión ya existe en **detalles_carrito** lo actualizo. `ELSE` lo inserto. A veces lo más simple es lo mejor. Luego ya puedes meterle más complejidad.

Comment: Concuerdo con @OCHOA  , si lo implementas desde el código buscando si tu producto ya existe actualizas (UPDATE), en caso contrario, registras (INSERT). Pudieras hacerlo en SQL creando un Procedure o un Trigger pero seria mas complicado.